# Newly installed system won't boot, how to disable k10temp from GRUB2?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, temperature, amd-processor

I just installed Ubuntu GNOME (via the minimal install, as no other Live CDs would boot) on a desktop computer which has an AMD Triple-core Phenom 8450 processor. The issue is, that after one reboot after installation, I cannot get the system to start in any GNU/Linux distro successfully. Windows 7 works fine (probably because it just ignores the issue), and here's why:

On booting GNU/Linux, the kernel boot log text (on screen while booting) displaying this error message:

```
[16.458331] k10temp 0000:00:18.3: unreliable CPU thermal sensor; monitoring disabled
```

and then the system just hangs there.

Now this would tell me that there is probably an issue with the CPU thermal sensor, except for the fact that I know that the temp sensor works fine, as I can see a live temperature reading from my BIOS.

So I did a little reading on the Arch Wiki and came across this:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lm-sensors#K10Temp_Module

The above article mentions that some K10 processors (of which family mine belongs to) have issues with their temperature sensors. This can be worked around however by adding the `force=1` module parameter to k10temp on load.

```
# rmmod k10temp
# modprobe k10temp force=1
```

or in `/etc/modprobe.d/k10temp.conf` add

```
options k10temp force=1
```

So I found my solution (or rather half of it). I just need to unload that kernel module so my system can actually boot. How do I do this from grub, and make my next boot honour it? The console syntax is not the same as bash environment.

Alternatively, how do I get a working Linux console up so that I can make these necessary changes?

Comment: I would do it from a live system. You mount the right partition and operate there, and then try to reboot to the disk.

Comment: oh geez, I've basically given up here and almost forgot about this question. The problem was that I couldn't even boot the machine past grub, because the kernel module (loaded by default) prevented booting iirc.